# save excel using EPPlus

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, epplus

could someone help me with this error??
I tried to save excel file using EPPlus

```
[IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Julian\Downloads\EmployeeMaster.xls' because it is being used by another process.]
```

here is my code :

```
Dim conn As New ConnectionVB
Dim newfile As FileInfo = NewFileInfo("C:\\Users\\Julian\\Downloads\\EmployeeMaster.xls")
Using p As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage(newfile)
   SetWorkBookProperties(p)
   conn.connect()

   Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = CreateSheet(p, "EmnployeeMaster")
   Dim dt As New DataTable
   Dim connString As String
   connString = "Select * from EmployeeMaster"
   dt = conn.openDataTable(connString)

   Dim rowIndex As Integer
   rowIndex = 2

   CreateHeader(ws, rowIndex, dt)
   CreateData(ws, rowIndex, dt)

   Dim bin As Byte()
   bin = p.GetAsByteArray()
   Dim path As String
   path = "C:\\Users\\Julian\\Downloads\\EmployeeMaster.xls"
   File.Delete("C:\\Users\\Julian\\Downloads\\EmployeeMaster.xls")

   Dim stream As Stream = File.Create(path)
   File.WriteAllBytes(path, bin) <- I got the error here
   Start(path)
   stream.Close()
End Using
```

Appriciate all help/advice with this error

Regards Siekh

Comment: I have to mention two potential problems:
1. To my knowledge, EPPLUS cannot open xls files, only xlsx files.
2. Did you open the file in Excel while running your program? If so, EPPLUS will fail. The File must be closed to be opened by EPPlus+
3. Another point: You are using the same pathe muliple times in the using section - this will definitely fail. I am very surprised that the File.Delete calls does not raise an error

Comment: As a final note: your code looks ...garbled to me. You did not use EPPLus properly - the first section is perfectly ok, but was is the purpose of the section after "in = p.GetAsByteArray()"?
If you want to store a datatable into a sheet, use Epplus .fromDataTable method

Answer (score 0):

As from your Error shows: EmployeeMaster.xls file is being used by another process.

Your code DryRun:

**In your EmployeeMaster.xls file you make another new sheet name as EmnployeeMaster and then you create Header, and Data in this sheet. 
problem arise when you write to file. you have to just save WorkSheet by doing .**
because just open your .xls file with the help of EPPlusPackage and then by code Add your custom sheet in .xls file and just save.

```
p.Save(); // you need to save this temporary sheet.
```

Problems may be:

- EPPLUS cannot open xls files, only xlsx files.
- Why you delete File. 
  solution: you can rename and then move.
- EPPlus hold your file when you instantiate object for ExcelPackage(with the same Path)

Answer (score 0):

Two Problems:

- EPPlus does not support xls files.
- For debugging why the file is used, I recommend using SysInternal's "process explorer", you can find it [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx).